# What should be done about this panama papers data question, now that new data has been released?

Tags: discussion

[Downloading the Panama Papers](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/downloading-the-panama-papers/7492#7492)

This question from a month ago ask for a source for the panama papers.

The highest voted answer said 'Very little raw data has been released yet'.

This changes today, as there will be a release today.

How should this change in circumstances affect the question? Should a new question be asked, or answers added to this one?

Answer (score 3):

I see no need for a new question, since it would likely be a duplicate of [Downloading the Panama Papers](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7460/70) anyway. Just add a new answer or update your existing one with the new information :)

Comment: Agreed. This type of issue happens each time new data is released. Just add a comment or new answer to the previous question.